# Trying to do a "top 1 / order by" in an Inner Join with T-SQL / SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

So here's my use case.  I'm trying to join on a particular table that can have multiple records in that table to be joined.

So, here's my query in its entirety, and the join I'm talking about is the first inner join:

```
select top 1 
    a.IN_Notification_ID,
    a.DI_Surrogate_ID,
    a.IN_Ref_Content_ID,
    a.IN_Name,
    a.IN_Description,
    a.IN_Category,
    a.IN_Rank,
    a.IN_Publish_Date,
    a.IN_URL_EN,
    a.IN_URL_FR,
    a.IN_URL_NAME_EN,
    a.IN_URL_NAME_FR,
    a.IN_HEADER_EN,
    a.IN_HEADER_FR,
    a.IN_BODY_EN,
    a.IN_BODY_FR,
    a.IN_ACTION_COMPLETE_URL_EN,
    a.IN_ACTION_COMPLETE_URL_FR,
    1 as 'IN_COMPLETE',
    getdate() as 'ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE'
from CXXXXXXX.Important_Notices_Inbox a with (nolock)
inner join CXXXXXXX.IGO_PROFILES b with (nolock) on a.DI_Surrogate_ID = b.email
inner join CXXXXXXX.PI_CONTENTVIEWS c on b.[user_id] = c.[user_id] and a.IN_Ref_Content_ID = c.content_id
where c.[timestamp] > a.[Date_Added]
order by c.[timestamp] desc
```

So, the first inner join that you see can and probably will return multiple records (there might be multiple records that meet the criteria a.DI_Surrogate_ID = b.email).  What I want to do is ideally perform a "SELECT TOP 1" / "ORDER BY _CustomObjectKey desc" in order to ONLY join the record that has the "highest" _CustomObjectKey value.  I hope this makes sense.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: As a side note you might read this article before you continue to splatter the NOLOCK hint everywhere. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `row_number()`.  But, in SQL Server you can use a lateral join -- which uses the `apply` keywork.  So the `from` clause would look like:

```
from C1397722.Important_Notices_Inbox a with (nolock) cross apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from C1397722.IGO_PROFILES b with (nolock) 
      where a.DI_Surrogate_ID = b.email
      order by _CustomObjectKey desc
     ) b inner join
     CXXXXXXX.PI_CONTENTVIEWS c
     on b.[user_id] = c.[user_id] and a.IN_Ref_Content_ID = c.content_id
```

Note:  I would advise you to use table abbreviations for the column aliases.  In your case, `ini` instead of `a` and `p` instead of `b`.  This makes the query much easier to read and to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ROW_NUMBER() function with partition by on DI_Surrogate_ID and order by  _CustomObjectKey desc.

```
WITH cte_data AS
(
select top 1 
    a.IN_Notification_ID,
    a.DI_Surrogate_ID,
    a.IN_Ref_Content_ID,
    a.IN_Name,
    a.IN_Description,
    a.IN_Category,
    a.IN_Rank,
    a.IN_Publish_Date,
    a.IN_URL_EN,
    a.IN_URL_FR,
    a.IN_URL_NAME_EN,
    a.IN_URL_NAME_FR,
    a.IN_HEADER_EN,
    a.IN_HEADER_FR,
    a.IN_BODY_EN,
    a.IN_BODY_FR,
    a.IN_ACTION_COMPLETE_URL_EN,
    a.IN_ACTION_COMPLETE_URL_FR,
    1 as 'IN_COMPLETE',
    getdate() as 'ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DI_Surrogate_ID order by _CustomObjectKey desc) as rn
from C1397722.Important_Notices_Inbox a with (nolock)
inner join C1397722.IGO_PROFILES b with (nolock) on a.DI_Surrogate_ID = b.email
inner join CXXXXXXX.PI_CONTENTVIEWS c on b.[user_id] = c.[user_id] and a.IN_Ref_Content_ID = c.content_id
where c.[timestamp] > a.[Date_Added]
order by c.[timestamp] desc
)
SELECT * from cte_data where rn = 1
```